# Problem with grails web app running in production: "No such property: save for class: JsecRole"

Tags: sql-server, grails, web-applications

I've got a grails 1.1 web app running great in development but when I try and run it in production with
an sqlserver database it crashes in a weird way.

The relevant part of my datasource.groovy is as follows:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDB"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {

        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            endUsername = "sa"
            password = "pw4db"
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ReleasePlanner;selectMethod=cursor"
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Message: No such property: save for class: JsecRole
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: save for class: JsecRole
Class: ProjectController
At Line: [28]
Code Snippet:
27: println "###about to create project roles"
28: userManagerService.createProjectRoles(project)
29: userManagerService.addUserToProject(session.user.id.toString(), project, 'owner')       
        }
    }
}
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: save for class: JsecRole

    at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.JSecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(JSecurityFilter.java:382)

    at org.jsecurity.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:180)

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: save for class: JsecRole

    at UserManagerService.createProjectRoles(UserManagerService.groovy:9)

    at UserManagerService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6fa73713.invoke(<generated>)

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)

    at UserManagerService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fcf60984.createProjectRoles(<generated>)

    at UserManagerService$createProjectRoles.call(Unknown Source)

    at ProjectController$_closure4.doCall(ProjectController.groovy:28)

    at ProjectController$_closure4.doCall(ProjectController.groovy)

    ... 2 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by deleting my database and creating a new database. I think some of the fields in my database weren't mapping correctly as I changed my domain objects. The error didn't really point me in this direction though!

Sarah

Answer (score 0):

This problem is discussed [in this thread](http://www.nabble.com/No-such-property:-save-for-class-...-td23667707.html) on the Grails mailing list. It is supposed to be fixed in Grails 1.2. A workaround for earlier versions of Grails is to add the following to Bootstrap.groovy

```
JsecRole.get(-1)
```